# What's this game: "You broke my robomatic machine!"

Tags: identify-this-game

I'm trying to identify a game from somewhere around ~1996-2001*. Played it on a mac

This was a [breakout-style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakout_(video_game)) game (I think) and the story was you were fighting some mad scientist who was making lots of robots so that he could pollute the planet. At the end of each level, he would say:

> you broke my robomatic machine!

Anyone know what this game was called?

* EDIT: looking at some older games on [here](https://www.macintoshrepository.org) I would put the release date between 1993 and 1997 based on my recollection of the graphics.

EDIT: this may have been an educational-focused game. I played it at school

Answer (score 2):

That *sounds* a bit like the Sega game, [Dr Robotnik's Mean Bean Machine](https://www.mobygames.com/game/7062/dr-robotniks-mean-bean-machine/), released in 1993, but I have no idea if there was a Mac port of it back then. There *was* one later, to Steam, but that wasn't until 2018 by the looks of it.

I'd probably call that one more of a Tetris-style game than a Breakout-style one (but they have similarities).

However, Dr Robotnik *was* a mad scientist in the "Sonic the Hedgehog" universe, and indeed had a RoboMatic machine for converting people into robots.

So that, along with the time frame if you're mistakenly remembering the platform you played it on<sup>(1)</sup>, fits well with your description.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Not trying to be disparaging there, but memories from 30-odd years ago are at least *potentially* unreliable. I can barely remember what I had for breakfast this morning :-)

Comment: It was definitely breakout-style rather than tetris style.  Dr Robotnik's robomatic machine has confounded any google searches I've tried. Its possible it was on a PC, but I played it in grade 2 and we only had Macs at the school.  Someone else asked about this gane on here: http://i-mockery.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-69698625.html, so I'm pretty sure I'm not imagining the whole thing.

Comment: @alex, that comment you refer to stated it was a breakout/pinball game, those are two *very* different genres :-) And you seem to be rather more definite in your comment about the style (your question states it was breakout style ", I think", which is what led me to believe that was less of a constraint). Given the Sonic universe was owned by Sega, the chances of an unlicensed game (without lawsuit) seems low to me, and a licensed game would probably have survived the Bit Bucket :-)